# Recommended Firebase data structure for my app

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

The question is about the data structure I have defined for my Firebase application.
It is working, however, I have doubts about the efficiency and scalability.

Imagine a chat application where there is only one global chatroom
but you will only see the messages from the users you have a relation to.
"Relation" in that sense means that you share the same group membership(s).
These are the groups:

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| Group A | Group B | Group C |
+---------+---------+---------+
| User1   | User4   | User7   |
| User2   | User5   | User8   |
| User3   | User6   | User1   |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

Note that User1 is a member of Group A and Group C.
The concept is that User1 will see the messages posted by User 2, 3, 7 and 8
whereas User4 will only see the messages from User 5 and 6. 
To achieve this, the relation of each user is stored in the Firebase real-time database as follows:

```
Friends
├── User1
│   ├── User2: true
│   ├── User3: true
│   ├── User7: true
│   └── User8: true
├── User2
    ├── User1: true
    └── User3: true
```

And so on. For demonstration purposes I am using the usernames here, actually, these are the Firebase UIDs.
Obviously, that requires writing a number of (users_per_group)² entries to the database.
The possible number of groups and users per group is unlimited.
The messages are added to Firebase like this:

```
Messages
├── User1
│   ├── timestamp
│   │   └── message: "This is a message"
│   ├── timestamp
│   │   └── message: "This is another message"
├── User2
    ├── timestamp
    │   └── message: "..."
```

The actual enforcement of the permissions is easily achieved by the following Firebase security rule:

```
"Messages": {
    "$uid": {
        // allow read only if the current user is a friend of the message creator
        // OR if the user is the creator of the message
        ".read": "(root.child('Friends/' + $uid + '/' + auth.uid).val() === true || $uid === auth.uid)"
    }
}
```

Is this the recommended way to structure the data?
I'm a bit uncertain due to the amount of data that is necessary to keep track of the user relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to disappoint you but unfortunately you cannot use this data structure for what you want to achieve.

First of all the performance of the data tree should be fine as long as not too many users are in the groups. I tested the performance of the solution by reconstructing the data structure you outlined and adding one player after another to a group while creating the "friend" relations between them in a Firebase realtime database. These are the results:

```
Added user #10. Needed time: 0.00156599283218384 seconds
Added user #30. Needed time: 0.00276100635528564 seconds
Added user #50. Needed time: 0.00490301847457886 seconds
Added user #100. Needed time: 0.013949990272522 seconds
Added user #150. Needed time: 0.0460770130157471 seconds
Added user #200. Needed time: 0.0947499871253967 seconds
Added user #300. Needed time: 0.451290011405945 seconds
Added user #400. Needed time: 1.81872600317001 seconds
```

As you see the performance seems to be totally fine for smaller groups.

But the problem is primarily not how you want to store the data but more how you want to obtain it. You wrote that you want to use database rules to get all the messages that a user is allowed to see depending on his "friend" relation. But this is some kind of filtering mechanism and filtering with the help of database rules is prohibited/not possible in Firebase Realtime databases.

From the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data)

> Rules Are Not Filters
>
> Rules are applied in an atomic manner. That means that a read or write
> operation is failed immediately if there isn't a rule at that location
> or at a parent location that grants access. Even if every affected
> child path is accessible, reading at the parent location will fail
> completely.

Also...

> .read and .write rules work from top-down, with shallower rules
> overriding deeper rules.

That means you would have to define some kind of read rule directly for your *Messages* parent node. But this rule would then override your rules for the respective sub nodes.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

When we are talking about efficiency and scalability, the most important rule in Firebase is to have the data as flatten as possible. According to this rule, i suggest you remodel your database like this:

```
firebase-url
    |
    --- users
    |     |
    |     ---- userId_1
    |     |       |
    |     |       ---- userName: "John"
    |     |       |
    |     |       ---- userAge: 30
    |     |       |
    |     |       ---- groups
    |     |              |
    |     |              ---- groupName1 : true
    |     |              |
    |     |              ---- groupName2 : true
    |     |
    |     ---- userId_2
    |             |
    |             ---- userName: "Anna"
    |             |
    |             ---- userAge: 25
    |             |
    |             ---- groups
    |                    |
    |                    ---- groupName3 : true
    |                    |
    |                    ---- groupName4 : true
    |
    ---- groups
    |      |
    |      ---- groupIdId_1
    |            |
    |            ---- groupName: "groupName1"
    |            |
    |            ---- users
    |                   |
    |                   ---- userId_1: true
    |                   |
    |                   ---- userId_2: true
    |
    --- messages
          |
          ---- groupId_1
                  |
                  ---- messageId_1
                  |       |
                  |       ---- messageText: "Hello!"
                  |       |
                  |       ---- messageTimeStamp: 1492189663846
                  |
                  ---- messageId_2
                          |
                          ---- messageText: "Hy!"
                          |
                          ---- messageTimeStamp: 1492189685692
```

In this way you can query your database very simple to display all the users that are appart of a single group: `firebase-url/groups/groupId/users/`. All the groups in which a user is appart:  `firebase-url/users/userId/groups/` and all the messages from a single group: `firebase-url/groupId_1/`

To learn more about structuring your Firebase database correctly please read this [post](https://www.airpair.com/firebase/posts/structuring-your-firebase-data).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I appreciate your response and agree that this is the preferred structure for a typical chat app. In my example, however, there is only one global chatroom and no necessity to keep track of the messages on a per-group basis. As you confirmed that the most important aspect is to keep the data as flatten as possible, I feel that I'm on the right track with my current structure. What I'm really worried about is the scalability aspect, e.g. when there is a group of 1000 users and a new user joins.

Comment: As you said, this is the preferred database structure for a typical chat application. So, in your case don't use the `groups` section.  In term of scalability, using this kind of structure, it will not cause troubles. I also recomand you to try a Real-World Case Scenario. Generate programmatically 1000 users. Be the 1001'st user and see what happens. So, best of luck and keep me posted! ;)

Comment: Is everything alright? Can i help you with other informations?